# Python unittest works from Pycharm, but not from Ternimal

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run my unit test with **Add content roots to PYTHONPATH** & **Add source roots to PYTHONPATH** setting in Pycharm (version 2017.3.2 CE) everything works fine.

[image]

But when I try to ***run terminal*** **or** ***unset the content roots & source roots to PYTHONPATH*** running in pycharm. It always says `ImportError: No module named ***`

My folder structure is like as follows:

```
-Project
-Controller
 -__init__.py
 -test_controller.py
-Model
  - __init__.py
  -model.py
-Tests
   -__init__.py
   -someunittest.py
```

when the test_controller.py call a method in model.py (Model folder) like 
`from Model import model`
it would always say **No module named Model**

Because finally I need to make others users  to execute my code without install Pycharm or something. I need to integrate the setting in my code.
Anyone who could help?

Comment: Ahh I love this  problem ;). Can you make your root folder a packkage, too? E.g. add a `__init__.py` to your root folder. Also, please show us your import statements

Comment: @ChristianSauer The root folder does not need to be a package. In fact some tools (for example nose) get into weird troubles when it is.

Comment: the import statement as like `from Model import model`

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm adds project root to `PYTHONPATH` by default, disabling **Add content roots to PYTHONPATH** prevents this behavior.

There's also an important moment to understand: when you run your script with `python path/to/script.py` Python adds the script directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

Take a look at the test run configuration, you probably have a working directory set to `Tests`, it means `Tests` is going to be added to `PYTHONPATH` by Python, and the project root - by PyCharm. Disable **Add content roots to PYTHONPATH**, PyCharm won't add project root to `PYTHONPATH` and Python won't find `Model` package.

To make it work from the terminal you have to pay attention to the exact call you make, e.g.:

```
cd <project_root>
python -m unittest Tests.test_something
# or
python -m unittest discover Tests/
```

is ok, Python will add the current working directory (project root) to `PYTHONPATH`.

```
cd Tests
python -m unittest test_something.py
```

will fail - `<project_root>` is not in `PYTHONPATH`, Python can't resolve `Model` package. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to the initial file for tests. Then it should work in either Pycharm or terminal.

```
import sys
import os
curPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
rootPath = os.path.split(curPath)[0]
sys.path.append(rootPath)
```

Comment: Did not work for me. 

Spec:
Xubuntu
PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-213.6777.50, built on January 27, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.25 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.13.0-35-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (2.18.2)
    com.chesterccw.excelreader (2.1.2.Tiger)
    Docker (213.6777.42)
Current Desktop: XFCE